# How do you Round it of in multiples of 0.5

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

first time posting

working on this project in BigQuery Where I want to round of the weight slab in multiples of 0.5KG

For example

- 0.4KG round it of to 0.5KG
- 2.1KG THEN round it of to 2.5KG

even if it is 50 or 100 grams above than the current weight slab than I want it to round it of to the next weight slab

I tried
`WHEN WKG.Weight_KG<=0.5 THEN WKG.Weight_KG=0.5`
but the output comes in boolean format

even tried this
`WHEN WKG.Weight_KG<=0.5 THEN ROUND(WKG.Weight_KG/ .5,0) * .5` 
but few of the numbers were rounded of to 0.0 instead of 0.5

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
case when round(weight * 10) % 10 = 0 then round(weight) else case when round(weight * 10) % 10 >= 5 then round(weight) + 1 else round(weight) + 0.5 end end as weight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
TRUNC(value) + CEIL(MOD(value, 1.0) / 0.5) * 0.5
```

For instance,

```
SELECT value, TRUNC(value) + CEIL(MOD(value, 1.0) / 0.5) * 0.5 AS rounded_up
FROM UNNEST(generate_array(CAST(-0.6 AS NUMERIC), 2.6, 0.1)) AS value
```

returns

```
value  rounded_up
-0.6   -0.5
-0.5   -0.5
-0.4   0
-0.3   0
-0.2   0
-0.1   0
0      0
0.1    0.5
0.2    0.5
0.3    0.5
0.4    0.5
0.5    0.5
0.6    1
0.7    1
0.8    1
0.9    1
1      1
1.1    1.5
1.2    1.5
1.3    1.5
1.4    1.5
1.5    1.5
1.6    2
1.7    2
1.8    2
1.9    2
2      2
2.1    2.5
2.2    2.5
2.3    2.5
2.4    2.5
2.5    2.5
2.6    3
```